# .class expected when typecasting

Tags: java, casting

I am getting errors,

- "error: '.class' expected"
- "error: not a statement"
- "error: ';' expected"

when trying to type cast from a double to an int in the following code.

```
double area = 4.33333;
int areaM = int(area);
```

The errors all occur on the second line. I have looked around and I can't find where I am going wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Help: do some research.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question. Spent so long looking at it I didn't realise I had my brackets the wrong way around

Comment: Questions aren't dumb. But sometimes they show that the OP can be more efficient by doing (other) kinds of prior research.

Comment: DO some RESEARCH

Answer (score 3):

You need to typecast like this.

```
double area = 4.33333;
int areaM = (int)area;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this;

```
double area = 4.33333;
int areaM = (int)area;
```

Answer (score 1):

this way:

```
int areaM = ((Number)area).intValue();
```

Comment: couldn't you just simply typecast ?